# Enlarge Image After TinyMCE Submit (View Form)

Tags: php, image, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE plugin for textarea and it work fine. So, how to enlarge image (zoom by click) in view form, after user submit? Is anyway to detect image extension, so user only enlarge image, not all inside field.

[image]

Comment: You should use javascript for this use case.

Comment: Thanks, it work using javascript.